# v-select sync modifier pass text with id from child to parent

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I have the following v-select in child component.

```
<VSelect
                label="Attribute"
                :items="addOnLabelItems"
                :value="addOnLabelId"
                @input="
                  $emit('update:addOnLabelId', $event)
                "
                solo
                outline
                reverse
                type="text"
              />
```

in parent, I got .sync modifier for `addOnLabelId`.  Turns out that $event passed in `$emit` is just only id of the select user chose.

Question 1): How can I also pass text with the id together?

Question 2) is it possible to include another sync modifier for v-select so that when select changes, it throws two `$emits` (one that throws id, and one that throws text) and in parent component, i can catch those separately?

Comment: You could create a method that does what you want, and hook that to the **@input**

Comment: yeah, but @input will only return id. then i have to loop through my items and find that specific object that has that returned id. when I find it, i should update it. that's what i didn't want - Looping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass in **objects** as items in a **v-select**, but you have to associate the **value** and the **text** by using **item-text** and **item-state**.

And if you want an object back, then you have to also add the **return-object** attribute to the **v-select**. (https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#customized-item-text-and-value)

**return-object** described in the Vuetify docs:

> Changes the selection behavior to return the object directly rather
>   than the value specified with item-value

HTML/Vue:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-container fluid grid-list-xl>
    <v-layout wrap align-center>
      <v-flex xs12 sm6 d-flex>
        <v-select
          :items="items"
          label="Attributes"
          item-text="state"
          item-value="abbr"
          @input="atInput($event)"
          @change="atInput($event)"
          return-object
        ></v-select>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</div>
```

And the JS:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: {
    items: [
      { state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL' },
      { state: 'Georgia', abbr: 'GA' },
      { state: 'Nebraska', abbr: 'NE' },
      { state: 'California', abbr: 'CA' },
      { state: 'New York', abbr: 'NY' },
    ],
  },
  methods: {
    atInput(event) {
      console.log(event)
    }
  }
})
```

Here's a working Codepen: https://codepen.io/mukagergely/pen/wVJLyQ

If you look at the console in the Codepen, then it logs that the **$event** returned is an **object**.

I also added **@input** and **@change** to the **v-select**, but you don't need both.

I hope this helps you solve your problem.